# How do we identify service shutdown time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, shutdown

How can we identify service shutdown time in MySQL community version 5.7.20. I presume that "statement/sql/shutdown" and "statement/com/Shutdown" are the events that occurs while shutdown a service, using this events I tried to set triggers to load the time. But I am unable to set the triggers too.

The way I identified is through error log. Do we have any other variable or a way to identify the time of last service down.

Answer (score 0):

There are three(3) ways using file timestamps:

## InnoDB Buffer Pool

If you have [**innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown) configured, look for the timestamp of the file that was written. The [**default filename**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_filename) is `ib_buffer_pool`. Mentioned this back on `Dec 06, 2017` ([Control InnoDB buffer pool allocation in MySQL (5.7+)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192506/control-innodb-buffer-pool-allocation-in-mysql-5-7/192570#192570).Since) `ib_buffer_pool` is usually written in folder set by `datadir`, you can run the following after shutdown:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
ls -l --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ib_buffer_pool | awk '{print $6,$7}'
```

## Binary Logging

If `mysql` has binary logging enabled, get the timestamp of the last binary log after shutdown.

## Error Log

You are probably saying, "I DON'T WANT TO LOOK INSIDE THE ERROR LOG !!!"

You don't have to. Just get the timestamp of the error log after the shutdown is complete.